# I18N and label() in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, label, locale

Is it normal if i use just label :

```
 label(user,:login)
```

it seach locale with only 1 key :

```
 I18N keys: [:ru, :helpers, :label, :user, :login]
```

If i use form_for:

```
<% form_for(user) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :login %>
<% end %>
```

it seach locale with 3 keys :

```
I18N keys: [:ru, :helpers, :label, :user, :login]
I18N keys: [:ru, :activerecord, :attributes, :user, :login]
I18N keys: [:ru, :attributes, :login]
```

This is confuse me. According help for label() both variatns should seach "I18N keys: [:ru, :activerecord, :attributes, :user, :login]" but it is searched only in the second one.

Comment: You're certainly right about what the documentation for `label` says.  Would you be able to edit your question to include the i18n files as well as any other code it references that seems to not be doing what you expect?